# How do I set the X-Values in a matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For an assignment in class, I made a number generator that writes the output into a file. I need to read this file and make a histogram showing how many values are in specific ranges like 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, etc. The problem I'm running into is that I can't change the x-values on the bottom of the graph. I want it to be the same as 0-9, 10-19, etc but I can't find anything online that'll let me change it to that.

This is my code

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
os.chdir("/Users/elian/Desktop/School/Scripting/Week 7")

with open("Random.txt", "r") as file:
    values = file.read()
    contents = values.split() 
    mapped_contents = map(int, contents)
    contents = list(mapped_contents)
    
file.close()


# histogram = plt.hist(contents, bins=binset, )
plt.hist(contents, bins=10)
plt.ylabel("Amount")
plt.xlabel("Range")
plt.title("Random Number Generator Histogram")
plt.show()
```

This is my first time working with matplotlib so I apologize if I'm not explaining everything right. I just want the histogram to show the amount of numbers that are in a specific range. I've tried `range` and `xlim` but I still run into the problem where the x-axis increments in 20s.

Comment: You can specify tick locations by changing the [default locator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating). It seems `MultipleLocator` would be a good choice in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The command for placing values on the axis is [`plt.xticks(ticks, labels)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). However, in case of a histogram, the values are automatically arranged as per the data and bin size. So if you change the bin size, you would be able to see the values accordingly.

Comment: The tick marks do not always match the bin size, and so you would need to specify them yourself after calling `plt.xticks`.

Comment: Sorry, that should have said "...after *by* calling `plt.xticks`"

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the x values in the bins parameter itself by passing a list of the values.

Example:
plt.hist(data, bins=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
The histogram would look as given in the link below.

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAjLS.png)